# "Low on storage space" But I have 1.7GB free space

Tags: internal-storage, 4.3-jelly-bean

I have a Alcatel OneTouch Star, Im running Android Jellybean the phone has 8 or 4GB storage Im not too sure but the low down is when i go into settings and look at how much free space i have it starts at 2MB then it changes to something like 250MB within a second then it changes to 1.7GB after 2-3 seconds. I have uninstalled all things I can, except for Facebook, Instagram and Snap chat. Its not the actual notification that Is bothering me, its the fact that I have 1.7GB of free space but the system doesn't let me download anything because it says that I don't have enough free space, so I think you can see why that would get on my wik, so can anybody help me? It would be much help

Comment: Can you give the exact error message? I have a guess here: "Insufficient storage" or similar? Maybe a look into our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) gets you started?

Comment: It says "Low on space" then underneath it says "some system functions may not be wotking"

Comment: OK, let me be a little more precise: You write "I have 1.7GB of free space". Question is: Where? Android devices have multiple storages. Most "low on space" messages refer to the device-internal storage (see the mentioned tag-wiki). So it doesn't matter/help in those cases whether you've got some Mega-SD-card with 1 TB free space – it's the internal one you need to check. So please, see the linked tag-wiki which already explains it all, so we don't need to repeat the basics over and over again :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that most phones seem to like a certain amount of space free, to keep things  running smoothly. If you try to downloaded something that would leave too little space free, it won't let you. Kind of like how Apple IOS system updates can required 4GB of free space though it may need less than 1GB in reality.

In any case,  your phone is capable of using a removable microSD card, and with the piddly 4GB of internal storage- of which only 2.5GB are available to the end user, that is exactly what the phone makers are encouraging you to do. You should invest in a microSD they are available in large sizes- 32gb is the largest without needed to format the card.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have a 8GB MicroSD card in the phone already, it is basically empty, it has maybe 2GB of music/photos on it

Comment: I think there's a way to make it so that apps download to the SD card automatically rather than internal memory.

Comment: Ohh really? I will go see if i can do that, thanks

Comment: That APP2SD feature was introduced with Froyo (Android 2.2) alright – but many manufacturers dropped support for it starting with ICS (4.0). So you need to check first whether the device supports this. If so, this would really help (as it "frees" some space on internal storage). Apart from that: See my comment on the question, the error message in most cases refers to device-internal storage (`/data`) only, not to the internal or external SDCard.